# Jpg to svg but source contains only lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, image-trace

Origami Crease Patterns contain every fold needed for the base model but they usually come in low resolution and bad coloring. I tried many options from adobe illustrator for tracing the jpg and creating outlines or whatever it could read.
**Is it possible to "tell" illustrator that the jpg contains only lines** so that it can create those lines automatically and then with a little grid snapping and manual editing i will have the same result in svg? (the svg file is more useful than just being easier to read)[image: CPexample 1]

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/nloPpIB.png) example 2

Comment: Problem is that jpg is horribly riddled with anti-aliasing and compression artifacts. Garbage in <> garbage out. Cleaning up the source might provide some help, but I was unable to clean it up enough to actually be useful here. If it were me, I'd simply take the time to redraw it. Especially if accuracy is imperative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Illustrator's tracing feature, but Inkscape supports multiple colors as the foundation for a vector trace of a bitmap. I used the image you provided in your second example, as it's much sharper than the first, pasted it into Inkscape and used the color portion of the trace feature.

It's reasonably sharp:

[image: origami image trace 1]

and the lines are clear, solid and reasonably uniform. Unfortunately, Inkscape traces both sides of a line, resulting not in a single vector, but pseudo-parallel vectors for each line:

[image: origami image trace 2]

When the node editing feature is activated, it's clear that the vectors are not straight lines and certainly not parallel, not that it would help any:

[image: origami image trace 3]

It's possible that the results of an Inkscape trace would be easier to manually duplicate, but it's still quite a large number of lines.

Comment: that's a very good result but if the final form isn't real vectors its useless. I tried different things like auto grid snapping script and aligning some nodes but couldn't get a good result. Any ideas on how to turn this into vectors ?

Comment: Even though the final form as shown in the image is "real" vectors, they are a spider web of curves and not a uniform grid of straight lines. I did not experiment with the great multitude of various parameters in Inkscape, which might have provided better results.